# Base trim before carpet?

Tags: baseboard, finish

I know it's an age old question. I will be doing all of our door & window casing in my basement finish this weekend. From what I've read, it's recommended to install the base trim before having the carpet installed? Is this OK to do if we don't know what carpet we are going with yet? I'm assuming I just install base trim 1/2" or so over concrete subfloor? This will give carpet installers enough room? Any other suggestions? Also, what space do I leave between door casings and floor, same distance?

Comment: I'm no expert, but if you're installing the trim before the carpet, that leads me to believe the trim goes to the floor, then the carpet goes to the trim. If you want the trim to overlap the carpet, hold off on trimming until the carpet's been installed.

Comment: I don't have experience with this, but I believe leaving a gap would allow the installers to slide the carpet under *during* installation, providing a hold to prevent curling up. The gap depends on the carpet and any underlayment. Why not check with the carpet store?

Comment: it may depend on the method of attaching the carpet to the floor. I'm only familiar with carpet tack strips, which leave an annoying hump right at the wall, making it difficult to put furniture up against the wall. If another method may be used, then do what's appropriate for that method. I agree that checking with the carpet installers you'll be using (or at least one or two options).

Answer (score 1):

The type of carpet can affect the height of the baseboards.

I usually set the gap at 3/8” this is normally sufficient but some really thick carpets need a full 1/2”.

When I say thick I am talking like heavy weave like Berber where the backing is heavy and the weave is thicker than 3/8 but most carpets will fit fine with 3/8”.

Comment: If the trim you are talking about is maybe 2" or more put it down first then you would put 1/4 round to cover the space between the carpet and wall. This way when you change the carpet it is much easier.